# python script to handle new mesh extruding

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, extrude

i working on a python real time script that run every time I extrude a face in a edit mode 
so i found that you can use handler to handling the new events in real time but i did't found any option in the document for how to handling this action

```
 bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move
```

so are there any way to make something like that ?

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):
    print("new face extruded ")

bpy.app.handlers.extrude_region_move(my_handler)
```